# Expandable ListView with SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, expandable

I have an SQLite database with multiple columns, and one of these columns is a date.  I want to populate the data from the database to an expandable listview, with the dates as the headings.  So for all the rows that share the same date value, I want to display them as children to that specific date.

I did it using arraylist to store the data from the database.  I got the group headings showing up but I get null pointer exception when I try to expand.  The error comes from the getChildView method.

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return infoList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        RelativeLayout infoLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.infoLayout);
        String exercise = ((ArrayList<Object>) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)).get(0).toString();
        String weight = ((ArrayList<Object>) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)).get(1).toString();
        String reps = ((ArrayList<Object>) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)).get(2).toString();
        ((TextView) infoLayout.findViewById(R.id.exercise)).setText(exercise);
        ((TextView) infoLayout.findViewById(R.id.weight)).setText(weight);
        ((TextView) infoLayout.findViewById(R.id.reps)).setText(reps);


        return infoLayout;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return infoList.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return dateList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return dateList.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView dateView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        dateView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        return dateView;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is how I populated the arraylists.  The arraylist containing the children are nested twice:  the innermost contains 3 objects to be displayed on the same row, and the "middle" one groups the innermost arraylists together so that they appear under the correct groupings for the expandable listview.

```
private DatabaseMethods dbm;
private ArrayList<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>> infoList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stats);
    dbm = new DatabaseMethods(this);
    dbm.read();
    Cursor dates = dbm.fetchGroup();
    int DATES_INDEX = dates.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date");
    while (dates.moveToNext()) {
        String date = dates.getString(DATES_INDEX);
        if (!dateList.contains(date)) {
            dateList.add(date);
        }
    }
    for (String date : dateList) {
        Cursor info = dbm.fetchChildren(date);
        int EXERCISE_INDEX = info.getColumnIndexOrThrow("exercise");
        int WEIGHT_INDEX = info.getColumnIndexOrThrow("weight");
        int REPS_INDEX = info.getColumnIndexOrThrow("reps");
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> secondInnerInfoList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
        while (info.moveToNext()) {
            String exercise = info.getString(EXERCISE_INDEX);
            int weight = info.getInt(WEIGHT_INDEX);
            int reps = info.getInt(REPS_INDEX);
            ArrayList<Object> thirdInnerInfoList = new ArrayList<Object>();
            thirdInnerInfoList.add(exercise);
            thirdInnerInfoList.add(weight);
            thirdInnerInfoList.add(reps);
            secondInnerInfoList.add(thirdInnerInfoList);
        infoList.add(secondInnerInfoList);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Show us a code you have tried and you will receive a help in case if you have any issues.

Comment: Elaborate your problem. If your code has error, post it here. Otherwise you can search [google](http://goo.gl/uZ1D1) for sqlite tutorial or SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6760948/1050058).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132559/java-lang-nullpointerexception-displaying-records-from-database-in-an-expandab
help needed .check out link ^

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a method to get and convert your data to an ArrayList or an array string.
2. In your Activity declare and init data for ArrayAdapter like:
   ArrayAdapter mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yourArrayListOrArray);
3. ListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing something similar.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For expandable listview with sqlite database: Instead of using BaseExpandablelistAdapter you can use CursorTreeAdapter. This will be easy for you to achieve the task.
Please refer the below link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getChildView(int parentPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view_list, null);
    }
    final String abc = (String) getChild(parentPosition, childPosition);

    TextView status_tv = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.child_tv);
    status_tv.setText(abc);

    //ImageView imgListChild=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_iv);


    //imgListChild.set
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: @coffeeCrisp can u please post your code.. Actually i also have same problem